# Unicode Scalars in iOS

Tags: ios, unicode, swift, ios8, core-text

Is it possible to create a custom Unicode scalar value in iOS or to map an existing value to a bitmap glyph?

I'm curious to see if one can create custom characters and strings like Apple's emoji.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_432), this is possible.

```
let customChar = "\u{5436}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. Do you know if it's possible to assign an image or glyph to the scalar value?

Comment: Don't think this is possible with Swift strings but it is possible with NSString as shown here https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CharacterSets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000146-SW3 (it is available in iOS)

Comment: I take that back, using NSCharacterSet, you are only able to create custom sets, *bitmapRepresentation* is simply a representation of the custom set. You'll probably need to make a custom decoder that inputs a unichar and returns an image or your desired glyph.

Comment: Maybe I could create a NSCharacterSet from a bitmapRepresentation and effectively define custom characters by removing whitespace from within the larger image?