# Parsing NSCharacterSet from a bitmapRepresentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, ios8

Is it possible to create and/or parse individual characters from a bitmapRepresentation NSCharacterSet so as to use in a keyboard extension on iOS 8? See [Unicode Scalars in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578183/unicode-scalars-in-ios) for some more background.

Also, can it be base64 encoded as opposed to unicode-based integers?

Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not make any sense to me. An NSCharacterSet uses a bitmap to store which characters are members of the set and which are not. That has nothing to do with the visual representation (glyphs) of the characters. – And what do you mean by "base64 encoded as opposed to unicode-based"???

Comment: Thanks for the response. So NSCharacterSet couldn't store custom bitmap glyphs? With regard to base64, I was referring as to whether NSCharacterSet, and the NSData objects it is comprised of, could be binary files (not simple unicode-compliant integers).

Comment: NSCharacterSet has nothing to do with glyphs. You can see it as a collection of Unicode code points, e.g. the set of all letters. A *font* contains glyphs.